# Kubernetes PV with Block storage over internet - Secure?

Tags: security, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I'm trying to create Persistent Volume on my k8s cluster with DigitalOcean Block storage, Using [CSI driver](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean).

It works fine, but I also wants to know that this is secure even for production.

I'm still looking for docs about PV security but can't find what i need.

I need your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be helpful to consider following overall security aspects to apply them on your Kubernetes cluster as described in [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/). I guess it can be a starting point for you to analyze potential security breaches in you Kubernetes Cluster. However, you can find some information about securing `Persistent Volume` storage below.

[Persistent Volume (PV)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) storage consists with essential strategies which you can apply using [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) section in a pod definition, like `Group IDs`, the `user ID`, and `SELinux` values.
`Group IDs` are global to the pod and applied to all containers defined in the pod. `User IDs` can also be global, or specific to each container.
Actually, there are four sections aiming to control access to volumes:

**`supplementalGroups`** - Supplemental groups are regular Linux groups. When a process runs in Linux, it has a UID, a GID, and one or more supplemental groups typically used for controlling access to shared storage, such as `NFS` and `GlusterFS`:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs 
          mountPath: /usr/share/... 
      securityContext: 
        supplementalGroups: [5555] 
      volumes:
      - name: nfs 
        nfs:
          server: <nfs_server_ip_or_host>
          path: /opt/nfs
```

**`fsGroup`** - Defines a pod’s "file system group" ID, which is added to the container’s supplemental groups. The `supplementalGroups ID` is applied to shared storage, whereas the `fsGroup ID` is used for block storage.

```
 kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ...
  securityContext: 
    fsGroup: 5555
```

**`runAsUser`** - User IDs can be defined globally to all containers, or specific to individual containers (or both):

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ...
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1000100001
```

**`seLinuxOptions`** - Possibility to assign [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) labels to a container with several values for access control security policies to identify level label:

```
  securityContext: 
    seLinuxOptions:
      level: "s0:c123,c456"
```